# error Command failed when I try install express-stormpath in other depends of express in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, git, express, npm

I am try to run this command :

```
npm i express express-stormpath cookie-parser csurf jade forms xtend body-parser --save
```

for install express-stormpath and create a app with node js epxress but I got this error in the terminal:

```
root@me:/home/memee/Desktop/home/nodejs/my-webapp#  npm i express express-stormpath cookie-parser csurf jade forms xtend body-parser --save

npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b 1.0.0-rc5 git://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-node.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4d0acf9a
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4d0acf9a': Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-07-22T20_52_51_690Z-debug.log
root@me:/home/memee/Desktop/home/nodejs/my-webapp#
```

I dont understand that error I think that should install  jade because the errro told me that here:

```
please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
```

[tutorial that follow](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app)

any help?

Comment: That Jade thing is just a warning. The real error is the `Permission denied` in the `/root/...` directory.

Comment: yep I know but because I got this error?

Comment: @juzraai this part : npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4d0acf9a': Permission denied
? but because I could not create leading? if I am like root in my system?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the jade/pug I believe it is a permissions issue. If you are on windows use the admin console and linux use sudo. Also install pug separately then run the rest of your install.

Comment: this part is my error : npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4d0acf9a': Permission denied ? but because I could not create leading? if I am like root in my system?

Comment: the problem is that I am like root in my system like you can see in el code that added I am like root in ubuntu